# Vertically align dynamic content children to the middle, but share the same "middle baseline" across entire row

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, vertical-alignment

If anyone has better wording for the question, please edit, I'm struggling what to even search when looking for answers.

I have multiples rows, each with three columns. Each column has a title and a description.  The lengths are dynamic and I would like to align all of them to the middle.  However, I want everything to align evenly - so the titles are in a row and the descriptions are in a row.  I am using Bootstrap 4 grid.

**What I want**
[image]

However, I was unable to find any easy way to resolve this problem.  I kind of figured it out using position absolute, but it causes the children to extend past their parent, and it creates some problems.

**HTML**

```
<!-- lots of these -->
<article>
    <h3>Dynamic title</h3>
    <p>description</p>
    <div class="hidden">
        <h3>Dynamic Title</h3>
        <p>description</p>
    </div>
</article>
```

**CSS**

```
article { position:relative; padding-top:30px; display:flex; }
.hidden { opacity:0; visibility:hidden; }
article > h3 { position:absolute; bottom:50%; padding-top:inherit; padding-right:inherit; }
article > p { position:absolute; top:50%; padding-right:inherit; }
```

If you look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jacobraccuia/bm3xzqhr/15/) however, I am unable to control the spacing between each row.  Position absolute pulls the elements out of their position.  It makes this solution seem subpar.

Is there a better way to go about doing this?  I don't mind using JS if necessary (or as an adjustment).

Comment: *I have a row of four columns* the picture shows 3 articles and the fiddle has 6 articles and your html says lots of articles, Can you be more specific ?

Comment: @ZohirSalak you're right - my numbering was inconsistent.  I have rows with columns.  The number of columns is irrelevant to the problem though, but I updated my question to be consistent.

Comment: Now is the number of columns irrelevant or *each with three columns* i don't understand

Comment: @ZohirSalak, The number of columns is irrelevant. If you look at the fiddle, I have numerous `articles` each with the class `col-4`.  This is dynamic content, and ultimately the number of columns will be determined on the screen size (bootstrap, `.col-6`, `.col-sm-4`, `.col-md-3`)

Answer (score 1):

If you go to custom instead of bootstrap(Because you have not mention which version bootstrap did you use.). If your paragraph same height.

**HTML will like this.**

```
<div class="article">
    <div class="box">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard</h1>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</h1>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and</h1>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS will like this**

```
.article {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
      -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto; }

.article .box {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
     -moz-box-orient: vertical;
     -moz-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-basis: 33.333%;
      -ms-flex-preferred-size: 33.333%;
          flex-basis: 33.333%;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 0;
     -moz-box-flex: 0;
      -ms-flex-positive: 0;
          flex-grow: 0;
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
      -ms-flex-negative: 0;
          flex-shrink: 0;
  max-width: 33.333%;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px; }

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .article .box {
    -webkit-flex-basis: 100%;
        -ms-flex-preferred-size: 100%;
            flex-basis: 100%;
    max-width: 100%; } }

.article .box h1 {
  -webkit-box-align: end;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-end;
     -moz-box-align: end;
      -ms-flex-align: end;
          align-items: flex-end;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
     -moz-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1;
          flex: 1;
  width: 100%; }
```

Here is [Demo](https://codepen.io/rahulmoral/pen/JjoWeWN)

If you use Bootstrap 4. [Example](https://codepen.io/rahulmoral/pen/VwYpVby)

**I made a solution using jQuery. Check above Bootstrap 4 example**

**jQuery Script**

```
$('.eh').each(function(){  

  var $this = $(this);

  var equalHeightSelectors = $this.data('eh');

  $.each(equalHeightSelectors, function( index, value ) { 

    var min_height = 0;
    var $children = $this.find(value);
    $children.each(function(){
      var $el = $(this);
      if($el.height() > min_height){  
        min_height = $el.height();
      }
    });

    $children.height(min_height);

  });

});
```

> Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for answering.  I'm using bootstrap 4.  Neither of your solutions solve the problem however.  The paragraphs are all the same height, which is why the columns appear to be aligned.  The paragraphs can also have dynamic amounts.

Comment: @JacobRaccuia I fix issue using `jQuery` Please check this https://codepen.io/rahulmoral/pen/VwYpVby.

Comment: thank you.  This does seem to work but I still have a few qualms with this solution.  I want the height dependent per row, and not per the tallest child.  As it currently stands, if one article is `500px` all of them would be.  I also need it to resize and recalculate (although I could figure that out).